# Reply/comment button not showing up - again

Tags: feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

I am totally puzzled.

Short story:
I can edit questions and answers on stackoverflow, stackexchange etc, but I can not post comments to reply to questions or answers.
Could be that the question discussion has been closed. But still, it does make little sense to me if I can edit, but not comment. Also, I really want to avoid the extra mile of having to ask on meta.stackoverflow to reopen a question.

In this particular case:
[How can I control the order of Drupal.behaviors?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/how-can-i-control-the-order-of-drupal-behaviors?answertab=votes#tab-top)
This should get a link to
[Is the order of fields in a javascript object predictable when looping through them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648139/is-the-order-of-fields-in-a-javascript-object-predicatble-when-looping-through-th)
or
[Elements order in a "for (… in …)" loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280713/elements-order-for-in-loop-in-javascript)

Long story:
I used to have the exact same situation before with a different issue, then asked on meta.stackoverflow.com, and suddenly the reply/comment button was back. They told me it has always been there, the thread was not closed. So I assumed I simply was too blind to see the reply button.
Now, same thing again, and there is really no reply button to be seen. Not anywhere.

So, here is what I suggest:

- Just allow me to post replies. Don't lock down old threads. Even if one of the answers was sufficient for the topic starter, there are plenty of people coming from google who might want to know more, or who can add some valuable details.
- Even if the user has no permission to reply atm, do not hide/remove the reply button. Instead, show it greyed out, and an explanation (on hover, etc) why it is currently not possible to reply. Otherwise, I feel totally confused, and think I am too blind to see it.
- Don't let me go to meta.stackoverflow.com each time I want a thread to be re-opened. This is totally killing my initiative.
- Make it easier to find my own threads/questions/answers/comments. I tried to find a list in my account, but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Btw, in this thread I can post comments. No idea what's the difference.

Comment: You seem to have 46 rep on SO. You need 50 rep to see the comment button. This is *your* question so that is different.

Comment: Ok, got it.<br/>
Still, at least for me, it is confusing to just have the reply button not show up.<br/>
And, it doesn't make sense allowing me to edit other people's questions and answers, but not allowing me to post comments.

Comment: You're only allowed to *suggest* edits. You need 2000 rep before you can edit without other people having to approve.

Comment: ah.. thought i already did edit something :) so probably this was "waiting to be approved" then.